# optimizing pandas code: replacing 'iterrows' and other ideas

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I'm new to pandas. I wrote a code I would like to optimize, but im not sure how. I'm aware of the fact that both 'apply' and pandas vectoriztion are faster than 'iterrows', but not sure how to use them in order to achive the same goal. iterrows is easy for me since its similar to 'for' loop, so I'm used to it. 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\temp\train.txt')

def group_df(df,num):
    ln = len(df)
    rang = np.arange(ln)
    splt = np.array_split(rang,num)
    lst = []
    finel_lst = []
    for i,x in enumerate(splt):
        lst.append([i for x in range(len(x))])
    for k in lst:
        for j in k:
            finel_lst.append(j)
    df['group'] = finel_lst
    return df
def KNN(dafra,folds,K,fi,target):        
    df = group_df(dafra,folds)
    avarge_e = []
    for i in range(folds):
        train = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['group'] != i])
        test = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['group'] == i])
        test.loc[:,'pred_price'] = np.nan
        test.loc[:,'rmse'] = np.nan
        train.loc[:,'dis'] = np.nan
        train = train.reset_index()
        test = test.reset_index()
        for index,row in test.iterrows():
            for index2,row2 in train.iterrows():
                train.loc[index2]['dis'] = euclidean(row2[fi],row[fi])
```

As you can see, there are 2 nested 'iterrows' loops. there is also 1 small 'for' loop at the top. 
The idea of this code is to assign the euclidean distance between every row of test to every row of train. But, since test is changed by the 'for' loop, it will eventually add up to all of the original DataFrame.

Here is the beggining of data:

```
   Id  MSSubClass MSZoning  LotFrontage  LotArea Street Alley LotShape  \
0   1          60       RL         65.0     8450   Pave   NaN      Reg   
1   2          20       RL         80.0     9600   Pave   NaN      Reg   
2   3          60       RL         68.0    11250   Pave   NaN      IR1   

  LandContour Utilities    ...     PoolArea PoolQC Fence MiscFeature MiscVal  
\
0         Lvl    AllPub    ...            0    NaN   NaN         NaN       0   

1         Lvl    AllPub    ...            0    NaN   NaN         NaN       0   

2         Lvl    AllPub    ...            0    NaN   NaN         NaN       0   

  MoSold YrSold  SaleType  SaleCondition  SalePrice  
0      2   2008        WD         Normal     208500  
1      5   2007        WD         Normal     181500  
2      9   2008        WD         Normal     223500
```

[3 rows x 81 columns]

Any ideas for optimaing this code will be welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide test data?

Comment: Do you mean: the first fue rows of my DataFrame ?

Comment: Yes, and what you would like to archive

Comment: data will be added in a minute. What do you mean by 'archive' ?

Comment: sorry, german autocorrect.... achieve

Comment: In the end, I'm writing a k-nearest neighbors algorithem. But here, I just want to culculate the distance between every row in train to every row in test.

Comment: If i interpret your code correctly you are overwriting the distance of the training set in every iteration of the test set. For one specific training example, do you want one specific distance or a distance for every test example? So do you you overall want to yield a 2d matrix of distances or a vector?

Comment: Well, What I want is this: for every test feature, culculate all disntances of all train feature ---> pick the 5 smallet ones ---> take the mean of another column of those 5 rows ----> return it.

Comment: Note, `.apply` is generally *not faster* than `iterrows`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two possible solutions to your problem:

-Using scipys [distance_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html)

-Writing your own numpy function

The scipy solution is straight forwards:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

point_vector_1 = np.random.random((10000,2))
point_vector_2 = np.random.random((1000,2))
distance_matrix = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(point_vector_1, point_vector_2)
```

In numpy we can use the outer ufunc to code our own function. np.subtract.outer will give as a matrix from two vectors similar to outer dot product would give as for multiplication.

```
def euclidean_distance_matrix(vector_1, vector_2):
  dis_dim_1 = np.subtract.outer(vector_1.T[0], vector_2.T[0])**2
  dis_dim_2 = np.subtract.outer(vector_1.T[1], vector_2.T[1])**2
  euclidean = np.sqrt(dis_dim_1+dis_dim_2)
  return euclidean

distance_matrix_2 = euclidean_distance_matrix(point_vector_1, point_vector_2)
```

Timings:

```
%timeit scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(point_vector_1, point_vector_2)
382 ms ± 8.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit euclidean_distance_matrix(point_vector_1, point_vector_2)
150 ms ± 1.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Edit:
To keep the original index you can pass in the index of the source df to the new dataframe:

```
dist_array = euclidean_distance_matrix([df1['lat'], df1['long']], [df2['lat'], df2['long']])
df_dist = pd.DataFrame(dist_array, index=df1.index, columns=df2.index)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion . It is a good solution. execpt that writing my own func loses the index and lables of the DataFrame, so I cant tell what vector in the new matrix was what column or row in the original vectors. Is there any way to prevent it ?